# filter json object/value from websocket and print to console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, websocket

Trying to print to console log a value from json data provided by a websocket

The code below prints the all of the json data from the websocket to the console log.

```
// require ws
const WebSocket = require('ws');


//messsage sent to  ws server
var msg = 
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "public/subscribe",
     "id": 42,
     "params": {
        "channels": ["price_index.btc_usd"]}
    };

// WS connection url
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://website.com/ws/api/v2');

//ws response
ws.onmessage = function (e) {

    // do something with the notifications...

    console.log('server : ', e.data);

};

//stringify json data
ws.onopen = function () {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
};
```

Expected result:

```
server :  5457.21

server :  5457.19

server :  5457.15
```

Actual result:

```
server :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1556209117657,"price":5457.21,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
server :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1556209117657,"price":5457.19,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
```

Comment: The code above is taken from the site's example itself [here](https://docs.deribit.com/v2/?javascript#deribit_price_index-index_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()`

This is how you could use it:

```js
    //This will turn it into an object you can navigate with '.params.data.price'
    try {
        console.log('server: ', JSON.parse(e.data).params.data.price);
    } catch {}
```

Comment: Whilst this does remove other data, it does not allow new prices to the feed. its just repeats the same data. I tried changing your suggestion  up a bit but still didnt work. It just kept repeating 'server:  5457.19'

Comment: you need to omit the `var e = ...` line -- that is just the output from your question, and it's overwriting the value of the `e` param that is being passed to the function. he included that line just so his snippet would work.

Comment: The data passes only upon an update. with each 'update' i t was just reapeating the hard coded value. I tried with your replacement but it did not work either :'( (omitted the var e = ...)

Comment: can you post your updated code so we can see if there's something else that snuck in?

Comment: Appreciate the help guys updated code to check [here](https://pastebin.com/vw1zvsC7)

Comment: There we go. Should be `JSON.parse(e.data)` not `JSON.parse(e)`

Comment: Still not working. :( TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Does `console.log("server: ", e.data);` still work? The new code is using the same variable as the original. However, if your function is getting called when there is no data, you'll have that problem since you can't parse nothing.

Comment: yes it still works :'( not sure if you can try it on an editor your end and youll see original works but yours throws errors :'(

Comment: Just updated with something that should fix the error.

Comment: This is placed just under the     ws.onmessage = function (e) { ???????

If so it too isn't working unfortunately :(  Do really appreciate the help

Comment: Tried it again :'( Ive posted my code again [here](https://pastebin.com/uiP7sY3f) just incase its incorrect.

Comment: This one should definitely not give errors. (I'm sorry I've resorted to bad-practice code :P )

Answer (score 0):

You are logging everything in `e.data`.

From the actual result json, it looks like you want `e.data.params.data.price`

As Robofan said, you need to parse it first.

`console.log('server : ', e.data);` -> `console.log('server : ', JSON.parse(e).params.data.price);`

Comment: Unfortunately this returns multiple lines from the websocket interface itself eg:
    server :  MessageEvent {
  target:
   WebSocket {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] { message: [Function], open: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readyState: 1,
     protocol: '',
     _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
     _closeFrameReceived: false,
     _closeFrameSent: false,